# Возможно ли использовать свою структуру таблиц с spring-security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Начал прикручавать авторизацию spring-boot-security к базе, и взял распространенную на многих ресурсах конструкцию для работы с ней через `JdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer`. Но столкнулся с тем что у него нет метода проверки по паре `username - login`.

```
@Autowired
public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery(
                    "select username,password, enabled from users where username=?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
                    "select username, role from user_roles where username=?");
}
```

Получается что я обязан иметь поле `username` в таблице `user_roles` и моя нынешняя реализация этих таблиц не подходит. Или ее можно как-то переиспользовать? Просто с методами в `JdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer` как то не густо или я не понял. Объясните пожалуйста используя spring-security я жестко привязан к заготовленной спрингом структуре таблиц?

Просто у меня такая:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
  id       SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  username VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  role     INTEGER            NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (role) REFERENCES user_role (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_role (
  id   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  role VARCHAR(10)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, свою структуру таблиц в Spring Securty использовать можно. Запрос `usersByUsernameQuery` должен возвращать два строковых поля и одно булевое, а запрос `authoritiesByUsernameQuery` два строковых. Как эти данные будут получены, из полей с какими конкретно именами - это Spring Security не волнует. В вашем случае достаточно просто воспользоваться [соединением](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)):

```
select u.username, r.role from users
inner join user_role on u.role = r.id
where username = ?
```

Тем, кто не пользуется boot'ом, проще всего задать нестандартные запросы в конфигурации `jdbc-user-service`:

```
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service
            data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="select username, password, enabled from users where username = ?"
            authorities-by-username-query="select m2m.username, a.authority from group_members as m2m inner join group_authorities as a using(group_id) where m2m.username = ?" />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Если система безопасности должна получать из базы больше данных, можно пойти немного дальше и написать свой [UserDetailsService](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html) и свой [UserDetals](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html):

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class MyUserDetailsService extends JdbcDaoImpl {
    private final String usersByUsernameQuery
      = "select login, password, enabled, superuser from users where login = ?";
    private final String authoritiesByUsernameQuery
      = "select u.login, a.authority_name from groups_users as m2m "
      + "inner join users as u on u.id = m2m.members_id "
      + "inner join groups as g on g.id = m2m.groups_id "
      + "where u.login = ?";

    ...

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsernameAndRealm(String username) {
        List<MyUserDetails> users = loadUsersByUsername(username);
        if (users.size() == 0) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found");
        }
        UserDetails user = users.get(0);

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = loadAuthorities(user.getUsername());

        return createUserDetails(username, user, authorities);
    }

    protected List<UserDetails> loadUsersByUsername(String username) {
        return getJdbcTemplate().query(usersByUsernameQuery, new String[] { username },
          new RowMapper<UserDetails>() {
            public UserDetails mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
              String username = rs.getString(1);
              String password = rs.getString(2);
              boolean enabled = rs.getBoolean(3);
              boolean superuser = rs.getBoolean(4); // Новое свойство!
              boolean accountNonExpired = true;
              boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
              boolean accountNonLocked = true;

              return new MyUser(username, password, enabled, superuser, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired,
                accountNonLocked, AuthorityUtils.NO_AUTHORITIES);
            }
          }
        );
    }
}

public class MyUser extends User {
    private final boolean superuser;

    public MyUser(String username, String password, boolean enabled,
                  boolean superuser, boolean accountNonExpired,
                  boolean credentialsNonExpired, boolean accountNonLocked,
                  List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired,
              credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);
        this.superuser = superuser;
    }

    public boolean isSuperuser() {
        return superuser;
    }
}
```